# IsNumeric Unable to Parse Query

Tags: sql-server

I have the query trying to count the emp start dates, and i keep getting an Unable to Parse query error specific to an )

```
COUNT([EMP_TNG_STT_DT])*CASE WHEN IsNumeric([LENGTH]) =1 THEN [LENGTH] ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Hours
```

Comment: SHOW THE WHOLE QUERY PLEASE. Also maybe if you show the table schema and the results you're trying to get, someone will write you an entire, working query instead of submitting 15 different questions involving invalid syntax and mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT([EMP__TNG_STT_DT]) * 
  (CASE WHEN IsNumeric([LENGTH]) =1 THEN [LENGTH] ELSE 0 END) 
  AS Total_Hours  FROM /* <Your Table or CTE or View or Whatever> */
```

Your still missing some other things the query probably needs, like a from clause etc. but I'm assuming that you left that out on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Because your parenthesis are not balanced (one `)` for every `(`). What is the `)` before `AS Total_Hours` for?